# iOS app WKWebView error when uploading image

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wkwebview, entitlements

In a `WKWebView` I am receiving this warning when I upload the image to our server using FormData via Ajax. The entire process completes successfully.

Can anyone suggest what is the missing entitlement.  I have reviewed entitlements related to `WKWebView`

In the console I see that the pid is associated with  "webkit.uploads"

"Required client entitlement is missing"
requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>

```
// xcode debug console on submit   
MyDomain[3002:428982] [ProcessSuspension]  0x104be68a0 - ProcessAssertion() PID 3002 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 3002
MyDomain[3002:427999] [ProcessSuspension] 0x104be68a0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
MyDomain[3002:428982] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x281b3b6f0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Required client entitlement is missing"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x100f2ee40; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}


// javascript upload code
var formData=new FormData();
formData.append("action", 'save');

var fileInput = document.getElementById('addImage');
if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
    var file = fileInput.files[0
    formData.append('messageImage', file);
    hasFile = true;
}

if(hasFile){
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/images/save",
       data: formData,
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function(result){}
    });
}
```

Comment: I do face the same issue. Pls update when you find the fix. Thanks

Comment: I could not identify a missing entitlement. Clearly this warning is related to the act of attaching a file to a javascript FormData object and submitting.  Other variations which I tested, for example submitting without the file, did not produce this warning. 

Despite this warning, I was able to publish the app on the app store without issue. As stated above,  the upload completes without issue.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. On safer side, I'm using the base64 string and posting to server.

Comment: Same problem here. Sometime the app seems to get stuck by this.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue in an Ionic app on both iOS and Android. The Android version fails at exactly the same point, but with a different message. The file is uploaded, but something prevents the response from being read, resulting in a null ref.

Comment: The point of failure I had was the API returning a 200 when the auto-generated API client was expecting a 201 - the noise from iOS was masking that issue by making me suspect a security problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hunch about this and other errors coming from wkWebView, and I think I proved it.  It has to do with the file uploads taking too long, and iOS complains about it, and wkWebView gets "released" (according to another thread).  In my case, my uploads were taking between 5 and 13 seconds.

I implemented my upload in a Web Worker, which turned out to be a little tricky on Cordova, but all of the issues went away once I did this.

Answer (score 0):

So my fix only seemed to address this in the emulator on my dev machine, which is using iOS 13.3.  When I build on my "production" machine running iOS 13.7 the error returns.  It was happening on both environments before moving file upload to a Worker.

It would seem Apple is in the process of adding something to iOS that is triggering these but has not yet documented or explained it.  That's my new theory.